# Objective-C : Trigger firedate from Integer variable?

Tags: objective-c, integer, uilocalnotification

i want to use "firedate" for local notification. How can i make use of an integer variable containing seconds to trigger firedate?

```
int intTime;
intTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5*3600;
notif.fireDate = (intTime);
```

I know that the above code is wrong, just give me a hint guys! Thanks in advance.

p.s. When i try to use this code i get "incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSDate * from int".

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Does it give errors? Does it not perform as expected? Be specific.

Comment: I edited the post. Read the p.s. please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fireDate` must be an `NSDate*` so as you are aware your solution is incorrect. If your calculation results in the seconds you want from the current time to fire then the following code would work.

```
NSTimeInterval time = ([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5*3600;
notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:time];
```

Also make sure dividing by `0` is not possible using `chargerSlider.value` by either setting the min value or checking the value before division. Otherwise the result would be `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

The `fireDate` property on UILocalNotification is of the `NSDate` type. You'll need to create an `NSDate` first with the the integer as the amount of time into the future you need. For instance if we were looking for a fire date that is an hour from now it would look like this.

```
notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];
```